# How do you continue with the original event loop after running a coroutine using asyncio?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am creating a python script that basically retrieves information from a webpage and sending a message to a discord server.

I have a main file that basically goes

```
import asyncio
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

def update(message:str):
    load_dotenv()
    TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
    GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        for guild in client.guilds:
            if guild.name == GUILD:
                break

        print(
            f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
            f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
        )
        updatesChannel = client.get_channel([CHANNEL 1 ID HERE])
        await updatesChannel.send(message)
    client.run(TOKEN)

def log(message:str):
    load_dotenv()
    TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
    GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        for guild in client.guilds:
            if guild.name == GUILD:
                break

        print(
            f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
            f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
        )
        serverLogChannel = client.get_channel([CHANNEL 2 ID HERE])
        await serverLogChannel.send(message)
    client.run(TOKEN)

while True:
    text = ['Text1', 'Text2']
    channel1text = text[0]
    channel2text = text[1]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete( update(channel1text) )

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete( log(channel2text) )
```

Currently, the script will only send the message on the first channel, but not the second channel, and it does not continue with the While loop. Am I missing something here?

Comment: How is `client.get_channel({Channel})` supposed to return `updatesChannel` in one function and `serverLogChannel` in the other one? Where do you define `Channel`?

Comment: Ah sorry, Channel is just a placeholder for the channel ID, it is hardcoded. Will update the question to make it more clear. Thanks

Comment: Also, are `update` and `log` intended to run one after the other or in parallel?

Comment: One after another

Comment: And do they connect to the same token/guild/... as implied here, or to different ones?

Comment: Same token and guild, just different channel ids on the guild(server)

Answer (score 1):

The core issue with your code is that `client.run` is a convenience synchronous function that will run the event loop, and run it forever, to keep the client going. That is also why your `update` function never returns. Incidentally, passing a synchronous function to `run_until_complete` doesn't work, and if `update` did return, you'd get an exception and Python wouldn't proceed to the next line.

To fix the issue, you can switch from `client.run` to `client.start`, which is async. You can also make use of the fact that both clients connect to the same token/guild and use only one client. That way the search for the guild can be done only once, and the `log` and `update` functions can be simplified to a simple `channel.send`. For example (untested):

```
async def send_message(client, channel_id, message):
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(message)

async def main():
    load_dotenv()
    TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
    GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

    client = discord.Client()
    asyncio.create_task(client.start(TOKEN))
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break
    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )

    while True:
        text = ['Text1', 'Text2']
        channel1text = text[0]
        channel2text = text[1]
        await send_message(client, [CHANNEL 1 ID], channel1text)
        await send_message(client, [CHANNEL 2 ID], channel2text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```